# Reading text against the editable field in PDF to UI

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

In my website, a client will upload different types of PDF templates which contain editable fields. I want to read the text and editable fields from the PDF and display the text with corresponding fields in my web form. I have found solutions for reading the text and fields separately, but I am not able to map the fields against the corresponding text.

Reading text and getting fields using itextsharp but not able to map that text and field. for ex: in the pdf it is specified as FirstName: Thomas. Reading from the PDF and display it in the UI as Firstname(label): Thomas (textbox).

sample code i have used to get all the fields,

```
public string GetPDFFields()
    {
        string pdfTemplate = @"d:\1234.pdf";
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outStream);
        var form = stamper.AcroFields;
        var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
        {
            sb.Append(form.GetField(fieldKey)+"\r\n");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What are the criteria by which you want to associate some page content text with a field as its label? Please be aware that in PDFs there generally is no direct connection between page content (e.g. your *FirstName*) and some form field widget. You essentially have to match them by their coordinates which might be hard if you don't know whether labels are in front of, above, or under their associated field.

Comment: So you mean i was not able to display the pdf content with editable fields to a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Try to read use this code sample 
http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/

Comment: yes, i have tried with this link. In that it only specified reading text as seperate function and getting all the fields as another function. I want to link the text with the fields to display it in UI as corresponding text and field.